# ansible docker-compose module problems

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I have an ansible playbook that can be run on different Linux/macOS based machines. And I have tasks which using ansible `docker-compose` module. And depends on OS running the playbook there is different error appearing, and it solving differently.

**macOS**

On macOS I see error  `{"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try pip install docker-compose. Error: No module named 'compose'"}` and when I'm trying to run `pip install docker-compose`  I see message `Requirement already satisfied: docker-compose`.

So first I think that probably ansible using different python version and I need to run `pip2` or `pip3`, so I consider to make a task in the playbook to install `docker-compose` module, in such a case ansible should manage how to install it.

Task:

```
- name: install certain python modules for docker
  pip:
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - { name: docker-compose }`
```

while running playbook I see that now ansible using `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to install `docker-compose` module, great ansible manage what python to use! But no, it's still not working and failing with the same error  `{"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try pip install docker-compose. Error: No module named 'compose'"}` on tasks that need to work with docker-compose, hmmm.

So after spending some time, I found the solution for macOS [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5522#issuecomment-259712617), now after I install `docker-compose` by pip from the custom directory it's working on macOS

**Ubuntu**

Same playbook running on Ubuntu failing with error  `{"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on  Python /usr/bin/python2. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter, for example via pip install docker or pip install docker-py (Python 2.6). The error was: cannot import name credentials"}` while trying to run `docker-compose` module related task.

Solution for Ubuntu is to run `pip3 install docker-py`

**Question**

What is wrong with ansible `docker-compose` module and how to make it work on all operating systems?? I can try to run different tasks depends on the os, but it's not a very clean solution